Order of automorphism group of generalized quaternion group
I was playing around in GAP and I noticed an interesting pattern when computing $|\mbox{Aut} (Q_{2^n})|$ for different $n$. For $n=3$, I am aware that $\mbox{Aut}(Q_8) \cong S_4$, however for $n > 3$, the pattern seems to be
$$|\mbox{Aut} (Q_{2^n})| = 2^{2n - 3}.$$
However, I only checked $n$ up to 9. My question is whether the formula is valid for $n > 3$, and if so, is there an easy way to see this?

Relevant: $$\operatorname{Aut}(Q_{2^n})\cong \operatorname{Aut}(D_{2^n}).$$

Combining the above with this should do the trick.

To summarise my comments into an answer:
Showing ${\rm Aut}(D_{2^n})\cong{\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})$ for $n\ge 4$.
and from here:
What is the automorphism group of $D_5$ (and, more generally, of $D_n$)?
$$\begin{align}
|\operatorname{Aut}(D_{2^{n-1}})|&=2^{n-1}\varphi (2^{n-1})\\
&=2^{n-1}\times 2^{n-2}\\
&=2^{2n-3}
\end{align}$$
for $n>3$.
Note: this is with the convention $|D_m|=2m$, so you're correct!
